# Error el mostrar un componente basico de react en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Este es mi primer proyecto en rails con react

Y tengo solo lo basico

En el **Gemfile** tengo las gemas correspondientes:

```
gem 'responders'
gem 'react-rails'
```

Creo un modelo basico:

```
$ rails g model Item name:string description:text
```

Y le agrego contenido al archivo seed:

```
10.times { Item.create!(name: "Articulo", description: "Esto es una descripcion.") }
```

Corro la migracion y el seed.

```
$ rails db:migrate
$ rails db:seed
```

En el controlador de aplicaciones tengo:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

Cree la carpeta api dentro de la carpeta controllers, y la carpeta v1 dentro de la carpeta api

```
app/controllers/api/v1
```

Dentro de la carpeta v1 cree el archivo `base_controller.rb`

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
end
```

y el archivo `items_controller.rb`

```
class Api::V1::ItemsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def index
    respond_with Item.all
  end

  def create
    respond_with :api, :v1, Item.create(item_params)
  end

  def destroy
    respond_with Item.destroy(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    item = Item.find(params["id"])
    item.update_attributes(item_params)
    respond_with item, json: item
  end

  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:id, :name, :description)
  en
```

Enrute los controladores de items en el archivo de routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    namespace :api do
      namespace :v1 do
        resources :items, only: [:index, :create, :destroy, :update]
      end
    end
end
```

Para procesar react cree el controlador `site_controller.rb`

```
class SiteController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Y lo enrute como root en `routes.rb`

```
root to: 'site#index'
```

Genero el instalador de react para agregar la biblioteca de javascript:

```
$ rails g react:install
```

Genero el archivo indexado dentro de la vista de site en concordancia con el controlador site:

```
app/views/site/index.html.erb
```

Y le agrego el siguiente codigo:

```
<%= react_component 'Main' %>
```

Genero un componente basico en:

```
app/assets/javascripts/components/_main.js.jsx
```

Con el siguiente codigo:

```
var Main = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hola Mundo!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Cuando levanto el servidor de rails

```
$ rails s
```

No se muestra el listado de los items y en la consola aparece el siguiente error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: React.createClass is not a function
        <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/assets/components/_Main.self-c3b95ff507d4b55ff6f053343b01763f2dfdbbf70c6b72f9c67284af54dee154.js?body=1:1

    Uncaught Error: Cannot find component: 'Main'. Make sure your component is available to render.
    mountComponents http://localhost:3000/assets/react_ujs.self-9a08a8b0d24192bc11429bb1ed503352257911d869094f0387e6b15021dc280c.js?body=1:322
    handleMount http://localhost:3000/assets/react_ujs.self-9a08a8b0d24192bc11429bb1ed503352257911d869094f0387e6b15021dc280c.js?body=1:367
    dispatch http://localhost:3000/assets/turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
    notifyApplicationAfterPageLoad http://localhost:3000/assets/turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7
    pageLoaded http://localhost:3000/assets/turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:7
    t http://localhost:3000/assets/turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1:6
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Rails estás usando? Veo en la documentación de `react-rails` que el proceso de instalación es ligeramente distinto dependiendo de esto.

Comment: ruby 2.6.6
rails (5.2.4.3)

Comment: Dentro de los pasos que describes, no veo que hayas puesto `rails webpacker:install` y `rails webpacker:install:react` que salen descritos [en la documentación](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#rails-5x) de react-rails o agregar `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` a tu archivo `application.html.erb` que es algo que deberías hacer por ser rails 5.